# Can't use display:table; together with text-align: center;

Tags: html, css

I can't use "text-align: center;" together with "display: table;" it only accepts the "display: table;" and when i delete "display: table;" the text gets centered but i want them both because the "display: table;" keeps the line at the bottom of the text as long as the text is.

This is my css:

```
h2 {
  margin-top: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<h2><?php echo ucfirst($category[0]['name']); ?></h2>
```

Comment: doesn't work either :/

Comment: Just add margin:auto for the sides ... check the answer below

Comment: @Mikic . I guess your solution should be to check if the variable is not empty and then echo the h2 tag. For clarity, check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`display:table` removes the block behavior of the element so now the width is defined by the content; then you can't see any visual text centered because there is no more space around it to center the element if you want table but centered on the page you can use the `auto` margins (center the entire element), check this snippet with background to see what is happen:

```css
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  background: tomato;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
}

.table {
  display: table;
  margin: 70px auto 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="table">My title</h2>
<h2>My title</h2>
```

Comment: works with centering it but puts the text at the very top

Comment: that's just for the example you can have later your margin-top value .... or add it on the shorthand the `auto` is just for the sides. Check the edit @Mikic

Comment: glad to help @Mikic

Answer (score 0):

This problem occur table width.

table defualt width is content width.

You set table width you want. maybe width:100%

Answer (score 0):

`display:table` and `text-align:center` will work together for sure if you mention a width for table. Because by default table will just take width of content inside it. So, you can set a width for your table, Like below:

```css
h2 {
  margin-top: 70px;
  border-bottom: 2px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  min-width: 100px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test text</h2>
<h2>Test text Test text Test text</h2>
```

I guess your solution should be: Use width but add a condition to check if the variable is empty:

```
<?php 
if($category[0]['name'] != ''){
 echo "<h2>" . ucfirst($category[0]['name']) . "</h2>";
}
?>
```

Comment: I think what the OP says "_keeps the line at the bottom of the text as long as the text is._" he means he wants the border bottom to only be has long as the text... like an inline type element.

Comment: Oh. I didn't understand that part. Now it makes perfect sense. So he can't just have width set to table. Thanks

Comment: Yes but i dont want a width as it has to follow the text.

Comment: @Mikic. I guess your solution should be to check if the variable is not empty. That way if there is no content then the h2 will not appear at all.

Comment: There is content doe :/

Comment: doesn't change anything sorry to say :/

Comment: May be I do not understand your requirement then. In the above case, if there is no content then there will be no line and if there is any content then it will always be at center. Is there any other requirement you have here